# Problem with finding a potential function of a vector field

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector

I have this code where I try to calculate the potential function of the vector field F.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
F[x_, y_, z_] := {x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
  z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}
p[x_, y_, z_] := x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
q[x_, y_, z_] := y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
r[x_, y_, z_] := z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
f[x_, y_, z_] =Integrate[p[u, y, z], {u, 0, x}] + Integrate[q[x, u, z], {u, 0, y}] + Integrate[r[x, y, u], {u, 0, z}]
```

The program do not give me any answer. Any advice on how to approach this problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you try integrating just one of the functions? Say `p[u, y, z]` ? Try dissecting your definitions of the integrable expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that you use `=` in your last line. This makes that the right-hand side is instantly evaluated. (a) this takes longer and (b) Mathematica cannot find a closed form, because basically, you try to integrate it with symbolic `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```
p[x_, y_, z_] := x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
q[x_, y_, z_] := y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
r[x_, y_, z_] := z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] /; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0
f[x_, y_, z_] := Integrate[p[u, y, z], {u, 0, x}] + 
          Integrate[q[x, u, z], {u, 0, y}] + Integrate[r[x, y, u], {u, 0, z}]

f[1, 2, 3]
(* -Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[10] - Sqrt[13] + 3 Sqrt[14] *)
```

However, your question is not entirely clear and I'm not even sure if you are after a general solution or just numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
ClearAll[F, p, q, f];
F[x_, y_, z_] := {x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]};
p[x_, y_, z_] := x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
q[x_, y_, z_] := y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
r[x_, y_, z_] := z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];

f[x_, y_, z_] = Integrate[
  p[t x, t y, t z] x + q[t x, t y, t z] y + r[t x, t y, t z] z,
  {t, 0, 1}]
(*  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]  *)
```

Or like this:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = Integrate[F[x t, y t, z t].{x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}] // Simplify
(*  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]  *)
```

This is just a direct translation of the [Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) for the straight-line path from `{0,0,0}` to `{x,y,z}`.  One could, if desired add a condition that `Simplify[Curl[F[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == {0, 0, 0}]` evaluates to `True`.
This formulation might make the relationship to the line integral clearer:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = With[{X = {x, y, z} t},
  Integrate[(F @@ X).D[X, t], {t, 0, 1}]] // Simplify
```

Note that the conditions on `p`, `q`, and `r` in the OP's definitions prevents symbolic integration.

Answer (score 0):

In V12.2, `DSolve` can solve the OP's problem:

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := {x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
   z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]};
DSolve[{D[V[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}] == F[x, y, z]}, 
 V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

(*  {{V[x, y, z] -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + C[1]}}  *)
```